# strip URLs but allow email addresses

Tags: php, email, url

Hi i am using the following function to remove urls but i found it also removes email addresses.

One thing I want is for users to be able to send there email address to another user but not send urls.

```
function cleaner($url) {
  $U = explode(' ',$url);
  $W =array();
  foreach ($U as $k => $u) {
    if (stristr($u,'http') || (count(explode('.',$u)) > 1)) {
      unset($U[$k]);
      return cleaner( implode(' ',$U));
    }
  }
  return implode(' ',$U);
}

$url = "Here is another funny site www.tinyurl.com/55555 and http://www.tinyurl.com/55555 and img.hostingsite.com/badpic.jpg";
echo "Cleaned: " . cleaner($url);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try using a proper regular expression to match URLs as opposed to something that just matches periods. Give this one a go: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Run it through [`preg_replace`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and you should achieve what you want.

Comment: I had a huge error with preg_replace seems to stop all my code from working, that is why i used this function

Comment: preg_replace is a core function and works if your regex works. What was the "huge error" you encountered? Any sane solution would suggest use preg_replace I'd wager.